# How to check if regex match with another regex in sql

Tags: sql, plsql

How to check if regex match with another regex in sql  , for example ab.* matche with abc.*

Comment: Check out [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) please ...

Comment: You also need to further define what you mean by the regex match. How do the examples you provide match.  The first will match the string `abd1` and `ab`,  the second will not match either.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is partial, I can only return a partial answer. If the regex goes through, it means it matches the regular expression. Same goes for the other. If you are trying to check if both go through, simply check if both of the regex statements are true.

Or.. If you are trying to see if both of the regex "match", you can compare them to a third regex, which should match both.

Or... If you are simply trying to see if they are equal, just compare them in an if statement.